# i have issue in nodejs api when i pass data in postman using body form-data than it pass null value(blank value) for input

Tags: node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDsgz.png)

I can not get value from postman body form data. from postman i am getting a null value(empty value). how can I solve this?

Comment: Your question is lacks any useful information for people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

try sending the data with `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `form-data` and see if that works

[image]

because for me i use this way